# How to use for loop to modify the object itself?

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of objects. Using a for loop I search for the object I want to modify and after finding my object I want to completely modify my object in `tempMach.lstnVar`. Below is my code:

```
    For Each var As ListenVariable In tempMACH.lstnVar
        If var.varName = newLstnVar.varName Then
            var = DeepClone(newLstnVar)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Deep clone function creates a deep clone of the `newLstnVar`. The loop assigns the value into `var`, but when the loop is done there are no change in `tempMACH`. I'm really confused how `=` operator works with objects. When I use `=` does it assign the reference or the value? When I declare a variable in for loop such as `var` in this case, is it just a variable with the same value in `tempMACH.lstnVar`, or is it a reference to it?

Comment: Is ListenVariable defined as a class or as a struct?

Comment: A `For Each` is not a `For`-loop ;)

Comment: ListenVariable is a class. I will edit the post accordingly Tim. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a [`For...Each`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) if you want to replace the object itself since you can't assign anything to the loop variable. Instead use a [`For`-loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx):

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To tempMACH.lstnVar.Count() - 1
    Dim obj As ListenVariable = tempMACH.lstnVar(i)
    If obj.varName = newLstnVar.varName Then
        tempMACH.lstnVar(i) = DeepClone(newLstnVar)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

You can use a `For`-loop only if the collection implements `IList` or `IList(Of T)`, for example a `List(Of String)` or `String()`. Otherwise you have to re-create the sequence.